# number input not showing value

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have several number inputs written in ruby. When I type in a number value inside the input, I assumed that whatever number is inside the field would show up as a value attribute inside the input html. But when I inspect the number input, the value does not show.

Why is that?

here is my ruby number input code:

```
        <%= number_field_tag 'xsmall', nil, in: 1...100000%>
```

[image]

Comment: We need more information. You're showing a snippet from an ERB template, but that isn't sufficient to "inspect the number input". Why don't you show us how you're inspecting it, along with the associated code? "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance."

Comment: I added a screenshot of what I mean. The value "2" is typed in to the field, but "2" is not showing up as a value = "2" attribute in the input html

Answer (score 1):

When you enter a value into an input, it will not show up in the HTML. the point of `value="2"` in the HTML is to tell the browser to pre-populate the input with that information

Comment: ok I see. How might I grab whatever number is in the field? You see, I am going to write a script that shows a certain amount of div's depending upon the number in the field. --if 2 is in the number field, 2 div's will appear

Comment: Are you submitting the form to the server first, or as soon as the number changes, do you want the divs to appear/disappear?

Comment: I would them to appear/disappear as soon as the number changes, an ajax solution I believe

Comment: Then use JavaScript or jQuery. jQuery is just a JavaScript library. http://api.jquery.com/val/ are the docs on how to grab a value from an input.

Comment: ok so .val will grab whatever number is in that field. It doesnt need to appear in the html first to grab it